# How to convert JPG to PDF without a huge file size?

Tags: pdf, images, adobe-photoshop, latex

I have a JPG file, scanned image of a document. It is a 2-page document and I united them in Photoshop. Now the JPG file is only 500KB, and the image quality is good. The JPG file's dimensions are 2481x5152 pixels

But the application form I'm uploading this document requires a *.PDF file format. I can think of two ways here :

```
1) Make a LaTeX document out of the image
2) Extract the image as PDF with Photoshop.
```

The 1st option does not work for me. Latex always adds extra padding and margin to the image, so the image is not readable anymore.

The second option, I tried, but photoshop Extracts a 40MB file, or a 130KB file (**Smallest File Size** in the PDF settings), but then the image in the PDF is not readable anymore.

Does somebody know a good setting in this menu, that will produce a PDF file less than 5MB, and with good quality?

Thanks for any help !

[image: Photoshop PDF Extract Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is with Photoshop.

The menu image I posted has a Tab "**output**" in the vertical tab panel.

In output tab, I choose image quality as `Minimum`, so that dimensions and resolution are preserved but the file size is nearly as the JPG size.

Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 7):

Download one of the PDF printer drivers, such as Nitro or PrimoPDF, and just open your image in Photoshop and print it with the PDF driver. We use these a lot to make excellent quality, small PDFs to email to customers.

Comment: +1 This is most likely simplest solution. Printing to PDF is stupid easy.

Comment: Another PDF printer: [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [JPEGtoPDF](http://compulsivecode.com/Project_ImageToPDF.aspx), a very light (236 kB) portable program which converts images to pdf.

According to its web page,

> This is a program for converting image files into PDF files.  The
>   program supports converting multiple image files to single or multiple
>   PDFs files.  The program also supports image scaling and positioning.
>
> This program is now written in VB.Net, and supports additional image
>   formats:  BMP, GIF, PNG, TIF, WMF, EMF, in addition to JPG, JP2, J2K. 
>   Also, This program now supports commandline execution, where the
>   syntax is: JPEGtoPDF.exe "pdfFileName" "imgFileName1" "imgFileName2"
>
> (Note that every parameter should be a full path+filename, and be
>   enclosed in quotes)
>
> This program now supports unicode filenames.
>
> Latest addition:  The program now supports multi-page images.

Comment: Thanks! This one does exactly what I want, and it doesn't recompress the JPG images.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Adobe Reader (10 or above, don't know if it works in previous versions) and if you have an original one with its key, then you can click on Create PDF online and you can select the pics to create a PDF.

You will need an internet connection for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). Open the image, go to `file -> export as`, change the extention to pdf or select pdf from the dropdown menu, and `export`.